# How to associate grade letters to values from a userinput arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm currently working on code that asks the users for their grades in a loop then outputs the highest, lowest, average, etc.

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to show a letter grade next to their valid number grade. For example: `79 (C+)`.

If anyone can point me in the right direction what I need to do that'd be great.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
        I know the code isn't the most efficient but im still learning how to use more methods so please
        bear with me for the beginning of the semester for the time being.
         */

        ArrayList<Double> invalidnums = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Double> validnums = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double totalinvalidGrade=0, totalvalidGrade=0;
        double sum = 0;


        //INPUT OF THE GRADES THROUGH THE ARRAYLIST
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter a grade: ");
            double grade = scan.nextInt();
            if (grade <= (-2)) {
                invalidnums.add(grade);
                totalinvalidGrade++;
                System.out.println("Error, Grade must be between (0-100); or -1 to finish");
            } else if (grade >= 101) {
                invalidnums.add(grade);
                totalinvalidGrade++;
                System.out.println("Error, Grade must be between (0-100); or -1 to finish");
            }
            else {
                validnums.add(grade);
                totalvalidGrade++;
            }
            if (grade == -1) {
                break;
            }

        }

        //Start of the GRADES SUMMARY:
        //PRINTS THE AMOUNT OF VALID AND INVALID GRADES POSTED.
        System.out.println("You submitted " +totalinvalidGrade+ " invalid grades");
        System.out.println("You submitted " +totalvalidGrade+ " valid grades");

        //PRINTS THE HIGHEST AND LOWEST GRADES ALONG WITH THE AVERAGE.

        System.out.println("Highest Grade: "+Collections.max(validnums));
        System.out.println("Lowest Grade: "+Collections.min(invalidnums));

        for (double value : validnums) {
            sum += value;
        }
        //return sum;


        System.out.println("Average: "+sum);

        //PRINTS THE LIST OF VALID AND INVALID GRADES:
        System.out.println("Here are the "+totalvalidGrade+" valid grades: ");
            for (Double valelement : validnums) {
                System.out.println(valelement);
            }
        System.out.println("Here are the "+totalinvalidGrade+" invalid grades: ");
            for (Double element : invalidnums) {
                System.out.println(element);
            }
    }
}
//EOC

//SOURCES I USED TO HELP DEVELOP MY CODE AND UNDERSTAND:
//MAX AND MIN GRADES: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/find-maximum-element-of-arraylist-with-java-collections
//
```

Comment: Minor point: Stack Snippets are for HTML/CSS/JS runnable code (but not for Java).  I converted the snippet to formatted code. See [formatting guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for help.

Comment: First off, "Lowest Grade" seems wrong: you get the lowest number from `invalidnums`. Is that intentional?
Secondly, well, what is the grading scheme? You write "79 (C+)", so I guess there is a scheme which says, e.g., 70 < grade < 80 is a C or something. Then you can print the number and the grade it maps to.